# Format specific text in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to format the specific String value which was acquired from Excel in Outlook.

Once the value is provided by Excel, macro will then append that value in the email message.

I tried testing and setting the value to BOLD but all of the contents of the message became BOLD. How do I format the value in such a way I can use the font type, size and color to my liking?

```
obj.HTMLBody = "<b>" & StrAgnt & vbCrLf & obj.HTMLBody
```

Comment: You will have to use proper HTML markups like `"<b>" & StrAgnt & "</b><p>" & obj.HTMLBody`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Working with Outlook HTMLBody](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2015/02/23/outlook-htmlbody-guide/)

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateHTMLMail()
'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties.

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    'Create e-mail item
    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim StrAgnt As String

    StrAgnt = "<HTML><H2>The body  HTML.</H2><BODY>Type the message text here. </BODY></HTML>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "<P><FONT FACE=""Comic Sans MS"" size=""6"" color=""red""><B>TEST.</B></FONTt></P>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "<P><FONT FACE=""Times New Roman"" size=""4"" color=""blue""><i>TEST</i></FONT></P>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "<P><FONT FACE=""Arial"" size=""3"" color=""green"">TEST</FONT></P>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    With objMail
       'Set body format to HTML
       .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
       .HTMLBody = StrAgnt
       .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

MSDN [HTMLBody Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171418%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)